# How to change the state of Arms of the Betrayers weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

So at some point my character is going to end up finding or buying the *Ruin's Wake* (The magical spear made by the *Arms of the Betrayers*).

My question is that there are three listed states – Dormant, Awakened, & Exalted – and I am unsure of how to change the state and which state it starts on.

Comment: Do you own the *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount*?

Comment: No, I don't own that book, @NautArch

Comment: Before asking a question about content you don't have access to, you should try and get that content to find the answer yourself. We aren't a source for info behind pay wall content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### They advance in the same manner as the Vestiges of Divergence.

The description of "[Betrayer Artifact Properties](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/egtw/wildemount-treasures#BetrayerArtifactProperties)" (*Explorer’s Guide to Wildemount*, p. 274) states:

> The Arms of the Betrayers advance in power in the same manner as the Vestiges of Divergence.

The rules for [advancement of a Vestige of Divergence](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/egtw/wildemount-treasures#sidebarAdvancementOfAVestigeOfDivergence) are spelled out explicitly on page 271 of EGtW. Of particular note is the property that their advancement is entirely up to the DM. The Arms are *sentient*. You can’t decide to advance them; they decide for themselves who they grant their power to.

Comment: @NautArch It’s conceivable in the upper echelons of certain wealthy black markets. In particular, it’s entirely feasible that Trent Ikathon or Lady Vess Dorogna of the Cerberus Assembly would shell out many hundreds of thousands of gold pieces for such an artifact, possibly from the Jagentoths, artifact smugglers based out of shady creek run.